# How to make a shortcut for this button?

Tags: shortcut

"Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to bring up **User Preferences**. Then go to the **Input** tab. Then expand **Image**, there you'll find **UV Editor**. Expand that and scroll down to the bottom and click on <kbd>+ Add New</kbd> button.

In the identifier, input this: `wm.context_toggle`. Then in the context attribute, input `tool_settings.use_uv_select_sync`.

Finally select an unused keyboard shortcut. I used <kbd>`</kbd> in this case. Select to **Save User Settings** so you don't have to do this every time you start Blender.

[image: Shortcut]

Comment: Worked as a charm, ty.